# Is there any model that can handle time ordered multi classification?

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, multi-class

I'm working on a little project and the task's the following:

There are transactions for 16 products and ~75.000 clients on a 18-month time series, where each row is one transaction from one client-product combination on a given date.

I've also got a list of 5 products for which I need to make predictions.

My goal is to predict for each client, which of the 5 products will they use in the following 6 months (if any) and in which order will they use them. So, my final output would look something like:

```
Client    Ordered predicted products

  1          A, C
  2          B
  3          -
  4          E, B, C, A, D
```

I don't know which model could help me with this specific task. I know LSTMs work well with time series data but I'm not sure if they work for this problem. Do you have any ideas? Please let me know if you need further explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This idea may lead nowhere but hopefully will lead you to a useful idea.  Think about stringing the data out into a tall and thin dataset with one row per month per client.  For each row create 5 indicator variables with $Y_{i} = 1$ if product $i$ was used by the client in that week.  Use a binary logistic regression model fitted separately for each product to estimate the probability that product $i$ will be used as a function of week.  Week would be modeled as a flexible nonlinear function, e.g., a regression spline.  Now the hard part: how to estimate the probability that product $i$ will be used before product $j$.  This may require modeling some notion of the correlation between the uses of multiple products.  I don't know if some kind of conditional probability model would help (e.g., $\Pr(\text{use } i | \text{use } j)$).

You can compute indicator variables another way if it helps, e.g., for each week have an indicator of whether product $i$ was used and it was the first product used at or before that week.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Frank! I was thinking something along those lines and your take is quite reassuring. I'll see if I'm able to work something out

Comment: Hello Frank, after some pondering I have a little doubt: if I use regression spline for weeks/months or I turn weeks into dummies I won't be able to predict for later dates right? As far as I'm understanding I will be left with the last spline for my future predictions or in the case of dummies, they would be a constant equal to zero on the training period. What do you think I could do? Thanks a lot

Comment: That's well said, and a spline requires far fewer parameters than using indicator variables.